# How to get exact type of object in Ruby extended C++?

Tags: c++, ruby

Hi. I'm working on a Ruby C++ extension, I have the following function, in which "self" object is either of structure type or of Exception type.

```
VALUE myFunction(VALUE self, VALUE args)
{
  // Some functon call and process on args argument
}
```

Now in the above function I need to know the exact type of object "self" (i.e. rb_eException or rb_cStruct),
I tried using the following API,

```
if(Qtrue == rb_obj_is_kind_of(self, rb_eException))
{
   std::cout<<"self is of rb_eException type "<<std::endl;
}
```

like above for rb_cStruct, rb_cClass etc but I'm getting only Qtrue for "rb_cClass" type. 
How can I get the exact type of "self" object (i.e rb_cStruct or rb_eException)?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not C (apparently C++).

Comment: Sorry for mistake. ya its C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the class with `rb_obj_class` which would be the appropriate `VALUE`.

Comment: Thanks Tadman, but when i tried rb_obj_class(self) in my funtion it returns large value (i.e. 46912519449080), so how can i get exact type of self?

Comment: Also i compared value retured from rb_obj_class(self) which is rb_cClass, i need exact type.

Comment: You could always convert it to a string using: `rb_funcall(rb_obj_class(self), rb_intern("to_s"), 0)`, right?

Comment: Tadman, still it returns large value insted of string as per your function call mentioned above.

Comment: I haven't done that much with C extensions, so you might want to post a question on how to convert a Ruby String VALUE into a C string.